# How to implement Salted SHA256 technique for the authentication in django

Tags: django-admin, django-authentication

So my application was recently submmited for security audit, and the auditor mention the the application transmits clear text passrod for login, change password and add user. I am currenly using Django for the application. The auditor has suggested to do use the Salted SHA256 technique
with following instruction

```
1. With each request to the login page, the server generates a random number, the salt, and sends it
to the client along with the page.
2. A JavaScript code on the client computes the SHA256 hash of the password entered by the user.
3. The salt is concatenated with the computed SHA256 of the password to re-compute the SHA256
hash of the concatenated string (let this SHA256 hash be A).
4. The result is sent to the server along with the user-id.
5. The server picks the SHA256 of the password for the corresponding user-id from the database.
6. The SHA256 password fetched from the database is concatenated with the salt stored at the server
which was sent to the client. SHA256 of the concatenated string is calculated at the server (let this
SHA256 hash be B).
7. If the user entered the correct password then these two hashes (A & B) should match. The server
compares these two hashes and if they match, the user is authenticated.
```

Is it necessary, and if so is there any package for this?

I tried the extending the admin login page using this template.

```
{% extends "admin/login.html" %}

{% block title %}Custom Admin Login{% endblock %}

{% block branding %}
<h1 id="site-name">My Custom Admin</h1>
{% endblock %}

{% block extrahead %}
<script>
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
        document.getElementById('admin-form').addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
            event.preventDefault(); // Prevent the default form submission
            
            // Get the password input value and the salt value from the context
            var password = document.getElementsByName('password')[0].value;
            var salt = '{{ salt }}';
            
            // Concatenate the password and salt
            var concatenated = password + salt;
            
            // Generate the SHA256 hash of the concatenated string
            var hash = sha256(concatenated);
            
            // Set the hashed value back to the password input field
            document.getElementsByName('password')[0].value = hash;
            
            // Submit the form programmatically after the hash is set
            event.target.submit();
        });
    });
</script>
{% endblock %}
```

And adding a view to admin

```
class CustomAdminSite(admin.AdminSite):
    login_template = 'admin/login.html'  # Path to your custom login template
    def login(self, request, extra_context=None):
        # Get the user model
        User = get_user_model()

        # Get the salt value from the database for the first user (assuming it's the superuser)
        try:
            user = User.objects.first()
            salt = user.salt
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            salt = ''

        extra_context = extra_context or {}
        extra_context['salt'] = salt  # Add the salt to the context
        return super().login(request, extra_context=extra_context)

custom_admin_site = CustomAdminSite(name='customadmin')

# Register your models with the custom admin site if needed
custom_admin_site.register(get_user_model())
```